# Display a column integrated in an echo and html

Tags: php, mysql, echo, display

I am stuck with an issue here. I am trying to read out a column (pdf) from my mysql db by php and show it on the website as a link. the column's value are pdf names of files saved on the ftp and i want to display it as a link on the page.

```
 <?
 $rs_news=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE ueberschrift_$lang NOT LIKE '' ORDER BY id DESC");
 if(mysql_num_rows($rs_news)>=1){
 ?>

<? for($i=0;$i<mysql_num_rows($rs_news);$i++){  ?>
<h4 <? if($i>=1){echo("style='margin-top:24px;'");} ?>>
<?= mysql_result($rs_news,$i,"ueberschrift_$lang"); ?></h4>
<img src="../news/bilder/<?= mysql_result($rs_news,$i,"userfile_1"); ?>" onerror="this.style.display='none';" style="padding-top:3px; padding-right:7px;" width="150px" height="110px" align="left"></img>
<?= mysql_result($rs_news,$i,"langtext_$lang"); ?><br><br><br>
<a href="../news/bilder/<?= mysql_result($rs_news,$i,"pdf"); ?>">Test</a>
<? } ?>
<? } ?>
```

I know my coding might be ugly, I am very new to PHP and trying to do simple things but I guess I think too complicated.
I have a DB with rows where SOME have a PDF value and some dont.
What I want is that at displaying it only picks those which have a PDF value and displays it via echo like this:

```
<a href="../news/bilder/<?= mysql_result($rs_news,$i,"pdf"); ?>">Test</a>
```

The default value in the column pdf is NULL, I tried to do it via if empty but didnt succeed.

Please let me know if you have any solution for this.

Thanks.
K.

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_`or PDO with prepared statements

Comment: You should give us a table structure as well as maybe some sample data to work with